# retain dropdown value after button sumbit

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

Hello I have this code for getting the categories according to department in a dropdown in my MVC website app

```
public ActionResult FillDDLCategory(int depId)
    {


        var categories = from c in _context.Categories
                        join d in _context.Departments
                         on c.DepID equals d.DepID 
                        where d.DepID == depId
                        
                        select new
                        {
                            title = c.CategoryDescription,
                            id = c.CatID,
                            
                        };



        return Json(categories);
    }
```

In my View

```
<div style="display:inline-block;">

        <select id="CatID" name="CatID" class="form-control col-lg-12">

            <option value="0" selected>-Select a Category-</option>

        </select>


    </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#CatID").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#departments").on("change", function () {
            $("#CatID").empty();
            $("#CatID").prop("disabled", false);
            var DepartmentID = $("#departments").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Tickets/FillDDLCategory',
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: { depId: DepartmentID },
                success: function (categories) {
                   
                   $("#CatID").append('<option value="0" selected>-Select a Category- 
                    </option>');

                   
                    for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
                        $("#CatID").append("<option value='" + categories[i].id + 
                     "'>" + categories[i].title + "  </option>");
                       

                    }
                                        
                   
                }
                
            })
        })
       
    })
       

</script>
```

When user select a department the dropdown menu is getting the according categories. The problem is that when sumbit the button for doing the search dropdown loses its value

I try

```
       $("#CatID").on("change", function () {
            var catID = $("#CatID").val();
            $("#CatID").val(catID).change();
            
        });
```

but no luck!

I use

```
$("#CatID").empty();
```

If I dont then the categories dropdown it keeps the categories from the department. But when the user select another department then the according categories are getting add to categories dropdown keeping also the previous categories from the selected department dropdown.

Any idea? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue of the quote while binding the Dropdown from>

I assume that `CatID` is an `integer` value so you don't need to add extra `single quote(')` while binding.

Change your appending line as per follows and it will work for you.

```
for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) 
{
  $("#CatID").append("<option value=" + categories[i].id + ">" + categories[i].title + "  </option>");
}
```

also you are appending the Dropdown so you need to add an event listener for that dropdown like follows.

```
 $("body").on("change","#CatID", function () {
            var catID = $("#CatID").val();
            $("#CatID").val(catID).change();
            
        });
```

after above change your onchange event will work.

Comment: thank you for your reply! I try your suggestion but the categories dropdown is loses its value again after submit!

Comment: Can you please show your html code

Comment: yes of course what part of it do you need? its is a big one with a lot of fields thats why I am asking...

Comment: Put whole html code

Comment: well it is huge since I have 20 fields for doing a search with multiple choices....I dont understand why you need the rest of html code...sorry

Comment: Required form with dropdown and submit so I can check that is there any other issue